Sums of reflective functions are anti-reflective and vice versa
I'm trying to understand Knuth's paper on Faulhaber polynomials.
A function is (anti-)-$r$-reflective if
$$
  f(x) = \pm f(y),\quad\text{for}\quad x + y + r = 0.
$$
Backward differences of $r$-reflective are anti-$(r - 1)$-reflective and vice versa. Inverse of a backward difference is defined as
$$
  \operatorname\Sigma f(n) = \begin{cases}
    C + f(1) + \dotsb + f(n),& n \ge 0 \\
    C - f(0) - \dotsb - f(n + 1)& n < 0
  \end{cases}
$$
Knuth then goes on to prove

Lemma 2. If $f$ is $r$-reflective, there is a unique $C$ such that $\Sigma f$ is
anti-$(r+1)$-reflective. If $f$ is anti-$r$-reflective, then $\Sigma f$ is $(r+1)$- reflective for all $C$.
Proof. If $r$ is odd, $\Sigma f$ can be anti-$(r+1)$-reflective only if $C$
is chosen so that we have  $\Sigma f\bigl(-(r+1)/2\bigr)=0$. If $r$ is even,
$\Sigma f$ can be anti-$(r+1)$-reflective only if $\Sigma
f(-r/2)=-\Sigma f(-r/2-1)=-\bigl(\Sigma f(-r/2)-f(-r/2)\bigr)$;
i.e., $\Sigma f(-r/2)={1\over 2}f(-r/2)$.
Once we have found $x$ and $y$ such that $x+y+r+1=0$ and $\Sigma
f(x)=-\Sigma f(y)$, it is easy to see that we will also have $\Sigma
f(x-1)=-\Sigma f(y+1)$, if $f$ is $r$-reflective, since $\Sigma
f(x)-\Sigma f(x-1)=f(x)=f(y+1)=\Sigma f(y+1)-\Sigma f(y)$.
Suppose on the other hand that $f$ is anti-$r$-reflective. If $r$ is
odd, clearly $\Sigma f(x)=\Sigma f(y)$ if $x=y=-(r+1)/2$. If $r$ is
even, then $f(-r/2)=0$; so $\Sigma f(x)=\Sigma f(y)$ when
$x=-r/2$ and $y=-r/2-1$. Once we have found $x$ and $y$ such that
$x+y+r+1=0$ and $\Sigma f(x)=\Sigma f(y)$, it is easy to verify as
above that $\Sigma f(x-1)=\Sigma f(y+1)$.

I understand the parts about the conditions on a constant. I don't understand the parts in bold: is it obvious that even a single pair of $x$ and $y$ such that $\Sigma
f(x)=-\Sigma f(y)$ can actually be found?

I got what Knuth was trying to say after rewriting the conditions. Conditions on anti-$(r + 1)$-reflective $\DeclareMathOperator\dint\Sigma \dint f(x)$ for odd $r$ are equivalent to
$$
\require{cancel}
\newcommand\pqty[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\begin{align*}
  0&= \dint f\pqty{\frac {-r - 1} 2} + \dint f\pqty{\frac {-r - 1} 2} \\
    &= \dint f\pqty{\frac {-r + 1} 2} - f\pqty{\frac {-r + 1} 2} + \dint f\pqty{\frac {-r - 3} 2} + f\pqty{\frac {-r - 1} 2} \\
    &= \dint f\pqty{\frac {-r + 1} 2} - \cancel{f\pqty{\frac {-r - 1} 2}} + \dint f\pqty{\frac {-r - 3} 2} + \cancel{f\pqty{\frac {-r - 1} 2}} \\
    &= \dotso \\
    &= \dint f(0) + \dint f(-r - 1).
\end{align*}
$$
Conditions for even $r$ can be rewritten in a similar way. Now
$$
0 = \dint f(0) + \dint f(-r - 1) = \begin{cases}
  2 C - f(0) - \dotsb - f(-r),& r > -1 \\
  2 C + f(1) + \dotsb + f(-r - 1),& r \le -1
\end{cases}
$$
By choosing $C$ one can make $\dint f(0) = -\dint f(-r - 1)$. That's exactly $\dint f(x') = -\dint f(y')$ for specific $x' = 0$, $y' = -r - 1$, which obviously obey $x' + y' + r + 1 = 0$. The last step in Knuth's proof extends the result to all $x + y + r + 1$ by repeatedly adding/subtracting 1 from/to $x$/$y$.
In the hindsight, no conditions rewrite is necessary, since they are already in the form of $\dint f(x') = -\dint f(y')$.
